# Downloading youtube videos using python's subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, youtube-dl

If I do this cmd :

> youtube-dl -i -w "ytsearch:funny animals"

Then it will successfully download the first video file with query name funny animals but when I wrote the same thing using python code

```
from subprocess import call

command = 'youtube-dl -i -w ytsearch:funny animals'
call(command.split(), shell=False)
```

It downloads **funny** instead of **funny animals** . Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your video name has a space in it... you could try splitting on a different delimiter instead.

```
command = 'youtube-dl|-i|-w|ytsearch:funny animals'
call(command.split('|'), shell=False)
```

---

More problems arise if your video name contains the same delimiters. A better solution would be to just pass the list explicitly:

```
call(['youtube-dl', '-i', '-w', 'ytsearch:funny animals'], shell=False)
```

Comment: Thank You very much! I need to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @blacklight When you do `command.split()` it becomes `['youtube-dl', '-i', '-w', 'ytsearch:funny',  'animals']`. Here `animals` acts as another option to `subprocess.call()` instead of being a part of `ytsearch:`.